# How to Query multi tenant Databases laravel 9 & hyn/multi-tenant 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, multi-tenant

I just inherited a new project which uses "hyn/multi-tenant" which I have not used before and their documentation is on a bare minimum level.

There's already about 450 tenants running on the multi-db tenant site, I want to know what is the best approach to query all ( 450+ ) tenant DB's, simple example would be to generate a list of all users in all the tenant DB's

Project is based on Laravel 9, hyn/multi-tenant 5

I don't want to use for each loops to loop and query 450+ DB's ( unless really unavoidable )